# Is it possible to create Safari Extensions without Developer Certificate?

Tags: javascript, safari-extension

Apple's Safari program is down and I can't create a certificate. Is there anyway I can make one without a certificate?

Comment: Unless you know someone else with access to the developer program, I doubt it's possible (stuck in the same situation).

Comment: I myself is registered with Apple but I dont have a certificate and Apple Developer site is down.

Comment: Site seems up again - https://developer.apple.com/account/safari/certificate/certificateList.action

Comment: @RobW not yet. On attemp to join Safari Program goes to this link:  https://developer.apple.com/iphone/urlRedirect.action?mode=enroll&successURL=https://developer.apple.com/ios/enroll/individualEnrollmentIndex.action&cancelURL=https://developer.apple.com/programs

Comment: "iphone"? Are you clicking at the right link? Try https://developer.apple.com/programs/safari/ (I'm already a member for some time, so I can't check whether the site is unavailable for non-members).

Comment: Safari. I am already iPhone Member and was trying to use same ID for Safari.

Comment: i only see http://devimages.apple.com/maintenance/ page. Are you able to log in and get Certificates?

Comment: its redirecting me to it: https://developer.apple.com/iphone/urlRedirect.action?mode=enroll&successURL=https://developer.apple.com/ios/enroll/individualEnrollmentIndex.action&cancelURL=https://developer.apple.com/programs